# Sharing large mmaped data file across machines in Linux Cluster

Tags: linux, memory-management, network-programming, cluster-computing, mmap

Say I have a 1 TB data file mmapped read/write from the localy mounted hdd filesystem of a "master" linux system into the virtual address space of a process running on this same "master" system.

I have 20 dedicated "slave" linux servers connected across a gigabit switch to the "master" system.  I want to give random read access to this 1 TB on these "slave" servers by mmaping it read-only into their process address spaces.

My question is what is the most efficient way of synchronizing (perhaps lazily) the dataset from the master system to the slave systems?  (for example is it possible to mount the file over NFS and then mmap it from there?  if yes, is this the best solution?  if no, what is a solution?)

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing around with an idea like this at work recently (Granted this was with significantly smaller file sizes). I believe NFS would be fine for reads but you might hit problems with concurrent writes. Providing you have only one "writer" then your idea should work reasonably well. If the data file is structured, I'd recommend going for a distributed cache of some description and allowing multiple copies of the data spread across the cluster (for redundancy).

In the end we went for a SAN and clustered file system solution (in our case Symantec VCS, but any generic clustered filesystem would do). The reason we did this is because we couldn't get the performance we required from using pure NFS. The clustered file system you choose would need to support mmap properly and a distributed cache.